# Rusty/Beginner C++ compiler error

Tags: c++

I'm a relatively experienced programmer, coming back into some C++ review for a class.  We have an assignment to write a couple relatively simple c++ programs.  Getting an odd error that I'm not used to, but I'm sure it's child's play for this community.

```
int pull_next_element (int r, std::vector<int>& sequence) {
    int x = sequence[0];
    sequence.erase(sequence.begin());  //orig: sequence.erase(0);
    return x;
}
```

Error I was getting:

```
Error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'
```

EDIT: Replaced with iterator instead of numerical index, and otherwise fixed this problem throughout the code.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is here...

Comment: Please indicate in the source you've posted which line is line 58.

Comment: FYI, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Numbering_permutations

Comment: Rudimentary problem solving process: Read the compiler error. Seems that you need to pass an iterator to `erase()`, not a value. Read the docs to confirm, yep... did you try this first?

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand the significance of passing an iterator, apologies on this.  I changed it to be the iterator, and updated the thread.

Comment: Whoah. Back up. Don't change the question. Please revert that edit. If you have a different question, post it as a different question. Also, based on the time interval between receiving the answer to your first question and asking your second one, you haven't spent enough time narrowing down the problem on your own yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use reference argument instead of value argument of 'sequence', or your erase will be useless.

```
int pull_next_element (int r, std::vector<int>& sequence)
```

Comment: Ah yes I overlooked that, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/

```
// erasing from vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  unsigned int i;
  vector<unsigned int> myvector;

  // set some values (from 1 to 10)
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  // erase the 6th element
  myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+5); // <====================================================

  // erase the first 3 elements:
  myvector.erase (myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+3);// <====================================


  cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++)
    cout << " " << myvector[i];
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While the answer is available at this link, answers that are just a link are discouraged because the link can become inaccessible. It is best to paraphrase the relevant section.